How to wrap long comments in code chunks in pdf rmarkdown output?
When I output my rmarkdown document as a pdf, really long comments don't wrap. For example:
x = 1 + 1 #This is a comment that will be written super duper long to see if it wraps around the document or if it trails off.

When I knit the document into pdf, the result is the comment trails off the page and does not wrap around.
I researched this problem and tried two things:

Downloading the formatR package and then using "tidy=TRUE, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60)" as an option in the {r} bracket. I made sure to use library(formatR) in a code chunk at the top of my document like so:

library(formatR)

I also tried using library(formatR) in the code chunk with the long comment as well as the "tidy=TRUE, tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=60)" option in that code chunk.

Using the below global statement:

knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts = list(width.cutoff = 60), tidy = TRUE)

The first solution did not wrap the comment like I wanted it to. The second solution wrapped long code but not the comment for the code. How can I get long comments to wrap, too?

A couple of options
Simple
One approach may be to put the comment on a separate line, then the use of formatR does the trick:
---
title: "Long code comment wrapping"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(formatR)

knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy.opts = list(width.cutoff = 80), tidy = TRUE)

```


```{r}

x = 1 + 1 
# This is a comment that will be written super duper long to see if it wraps around the document or if it trails off.

```

This results in:

LaTeX package listings
An alternative approach is to use the LaTeX package listings and a helper file: wrapping.tex with the above adjustments in the YAML header. This is a bit more work but I suspect would offer more control and formatting options which I have not explored.
This has been adapted from guidance in bookdown:
Create a file in the working directory (arbitrarily named wrapping.tex in this instance) with this code:
\lstset{
  breaklines=true
}

Checkout the listings package on CTAN for a full list of options.
Then try this in your markdown document:
---
title: "Long code comment wrapping using listings package"
output:
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: --listings
    includes:
      in_header: wrapping.tex
---


```{r}

x = 1 + 1 # This is a comment that will be written super duper long to see if it wraps around the document or if it trails off.

```

Which results in:

